# Mount a Folder as a Drive (Junction)?

Tags: windows-xp, mount

I would like to Mount a Folder as a Letter using Windows XP.
E.g. I want c:\MyFolder to be mounted as M:\

How to achive this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the subst command.

```
subst m: c:\myfolder
```